# Local AngularJS application hosted in WKWebView

Tags: angularjs, swift, cross-domain

I have a hybrid application built using a WKWebView.  I have gotten around the loading local files issue, but I am having trouble loading an AngularJS application from local files.  I am getting the following error:

> Cross origin requests are only supported fro HTTP.

With Android I was able to update setting on the WebView control to allow this from file:// schemes.  Is there anything similar that I am missing in iOS?  Or another solution?

I am using XCode 6.3 (6D570)

Comment: No one has another answer? Is the only solution to run UIWebView? That's incredibly frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with `WKWebView` in iOS 8, and I suspect that's why `UIWebView` remains undeprecated.

I haven't had time to use the betas yet, but my only suggestion is to give the latest Xcode 7/iOS 9 a shot, and use the new `WKWebView` API

`- (WKNavigation * _Nullable)loadFileURL:(NSURL * _Nonnull)URL allowingReadAccessToURL:(NSURL * _Nonnull)readAccessURL`

which would ideally let you pull in other HTML files as templates in the `readAccessURL` that you provide.

Please file any bugs you see in the latest beta. Apple is way too slow to move on the issues in `WKWebView`.

If you just need the Angular app to work **now**, then you'll need to switch to `UIWebView`, which is confirmed to work with angular-based webapps stored on the device.

Comment: Any development on this @ray? I tried to use it without success. Anyone could?